# How can I fix my code to save 3 values in array using php, mysql to make a survey?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, survey

Hello I am trying to make a survey using php and Mysql, with the code below I save every answer per questions, but When I tried to save comments_per_questions it did not save that field into the array it only save one comment.

How can I fix this function to save into the database Questions, Answers and Comments per questions?

Thanks in advance.

***Database Structure***

```
"Questions" (idquestion, question)

"Surveys" (idsurvey, idquestion, answers, comments_per_question, survey_number)
```

***This part of code save the question and answers from the survey form.***

```
public function NewSurveyMulti($answer = array())
{           
    if(!empty($answer)) {
        foreach($answer as $questi => $value  ) {
            $this->MyDB->Write("INSERT INTO surveys (`idquestion`, `answers`,`comments_per_questions` )
                    VALUES( 
                    '".$questi."', 
                    '".$value[0]."',
                    '".$_POST["comment"]."')");
        }
    }
```

***survey_form.php***

```
<?php
    // Fetch questions
    $cuestionario   =   $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM questions"); ?>

    <form name="newDona" action="" method="post">
    </table><?php
    // Confirm there are questions being drawn from database
    $numrows        =   (is_array($cuestionario))? count($cuestionario): 0;
    if($numrows > 0) {
            // Loop through questions
            foreach($cuestionario as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <!-- Write the question -->
                <td><?php echo $row["question"];?></td>
            </tr>
            <th>
                <!-- Set the question id -->
                <select name="answer[<?php echo $row['idquestion']; ?>][]">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">yes</option>
                    <option value="no">NO</option>
                </select>
            </th><?php 


    <th><textarea type="text" name="comment" maxlength="50" cols="130" rows="5"/ ></textarea></th>


                     } ?>


<tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="SAVE" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: how do you want to save comments??

Comment: Where do you get $_POST from? What's it's var_dump

Comment: I want to save the comments getting from a survey form, and the $_POST ["comment"] I get it from the <textarea name=comment> which is located into the survey form

Comment: It might be an idea to show how `$answer` is being populated.

Comment: I already edited my post adding the form survey_form.php from I get those values.

Comment: I'm confused. The loop is around the questions - there is only one comment field.

Comment: yes you are right, I edited the post and I inserted the comment field into the loop, but it does not work, It only save an empty space into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now the question shows the comment field within the loop, do what you did with the select.

```
<textarea type="text" name="comment[<?php echo $row['idquestion']; ?>]" maxlength="50" cols="130" rows="5"/ >
```

and collect it in your loop with

```
$_POST["comment"][$questi]
```

*ASIDE: You should [prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) as your code leaves your site vulnerable to attack.*

Comment: I already added your code but when I submit the form, the database save a value "Array" in the field, do you know why ?

Comment: Thank you very much Popnoodles, It works perfectly, I really appreciate your help, :D, I have a little question, do you know how can I convert the INSERT query into UPDATE query?, I'm learning  PDO, it is new for me those queries

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example :

```
<?php

echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<textarea name="comments[]" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>';
echo '<textarea name="comments[]" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>';
echo '<textarea name="comments[]" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>';
echo '<button name="submit">Submit</button>';
echo '</form>';

if (isset($_POST['comments']))
{
    var_dump($_POST['comments']);
}
```